# convergence of $\{\sin(1/n)\}$ sequence using limit definition?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

how to prove convergence of  $\{\sin(1/n)\}$ sequence when $n$ goes infinity, using limit definition?
I proved that $\{\sin(n)\}$ is divergent but i can not do this with that method.

Comment: The proof should resemble a demonstration that $\sin(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: *Hint:* For all positive integers $n$,

$$|\sin (1/n) - 0| \  \leq \  |1/n - 0|$$

Comment: oh goodness! thanks man. I think it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$.
$\sin(x)$ is continueous at $x=0$ and $\sin(0)=0$.

As a result there exists $a>0$ such that $\forall x\in[-a,a],|\sin(x)|<\epsilon$.

What is more since $\lim_\infty\frac{1}n=0$ we have $N>0$ such that $\forall n\ge N,\left|\frac{1}n\right|<a$.

As a result $\forall n>N,|\sin(\frac{1}n)|<\epsilon$.

Conclusion : $\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(\frac{1}n)=0}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Notice that if this sequence is convergent, then it has to be Cauchy. If sequence $\{\sin\frac{1}{n}\}$ does not converge, then there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$, $m,n>N$ implies $|\sin\frac{1}{n}-\sin\frac{1}{m}|\ge \epsilon.$ What if we let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: If 'there exists an $\epsilon$', we may not know its value, and can't proceed to let $\epsilon=\frac12$.

Comment: @paw88789 When we actually write down the proof, we would let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ then I would be able to show you that as we go furthur, we can always find two terms that are $\frac{1}{2}$ apart, which implies the sequence cannot be convergent. As long as you choose $\epsilon$ as something less than $1$.

Comment: I agree that always being able to find terms at least $\frac12$ apart is sufficient for the sequence to diverge, it is not necessary.

Comment: @paw88789 I'm sorry but you lost me. Are you saying this proof is wrong? Or are you saying that there is simpler way of doing it?

Comment: I'm saying that being able to show that all the terms beyond some point are within $\frac12$ of each other is not enough to show that the sequence is converging.  Or equivalently, the sequence diverging doesn't necessarily mean that we will find terms that are more than $\frac12$ apart.

Comment: @paw88789 Yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Here is the proof that $\sin x$ is continuous at $0$. Can you see how to use this?

Recall $|\sin x|\le|x|$. Now, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta=\epsilon$ such that whenever $\left|x-0\right|<\delta$ then $|\sin x-0|\le |x|<\delta=\epsilon$. Hence $\sin x$ is continuous at $0$.